# jquery and wordpress enqueue

Tags: jquery, wordpress

If I enqueue jquery from my own server everything works fine and dandy:

```
add_action('init', 'headsetup');

function headsetup(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery_script',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-.8.3.min.js');
}
```

but if I use the built in wordpress jquery everything falls over:

```
add_action('init', 'headsetup');

function headsetup(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Jquery is loading, I can see it in the site `<head>` but it's not triggering which means the scripts that follow don't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: if your in firefox, press CTRL + SHIFT + K, it will tell you if jquery has loaded, then go from there

Comment: Where are you trying to enqueue jquery?

Comment: @Edgar: In functions.php. It works perfectly if I enqueue from my server but if I use the built in wordpress jquery it doesn't. The enqueue is in exactly the same place in functions.php

Comment: I mean where are you trying to use the jquery? In your admin pages? On all of your pages?

Comment: @Connor: no js errors reported

Comment: @EdgarAllanPwn: sorry. On all my pages. Like this one: [link](http://testblog.co.uk/responsive-image-test/). This is the working version. If I use 'wp_enqueue_script('jquery');' I can see the js file in the document head but it doesn't seem to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted!

All I had to do was change the way I called jquery.

Instead of:

```
$("somefunction")
```

It has to be:

```
jQuery("somefunction")
```

It's a wordpress thing...